# How to extract pkcs7 envelop contents and verify digital signature?

Tags: c, openssl, x509certificate, pkcs#7

I want to verify the digital signature of the pkcs7 envelop .
PKCS7 envelop has message content,signer certificate, signature in it.
How to extract this parts ?
And how to verify digital signature ?

Also I want to check the authenticity of the signer certificate which is a x509 digital certificate .

Answer (score 2):

If you have the PKCS7 message in an OpenSSL `PKCS7 *` object, you can simply use `PKCS7_verify()`.  It will verify the signature and the certificate using the supplied trusted certificate store.

If the message is in `S/MIME` format, the `SMIME_read_PKCS7()` function can be used to turn it into a `PKCS7 *` object.